# How can I rename a particular variable throughout the whole program?

Tags: java, variables, replace, bluej

How can I change a particular variable to some other throughout the whole program?

For example, I have made an array `L` which has quantity, and I want to switch `L` with `qty` throughout the program!

Find and replace will take forever. Any other method that I can use here?

Comment: Because brother SO community believe first you should find your answer by searching and trying at your end. When you do not find appropriate answer or solution, then ask help from community. Rest everybody is here to help each other. :-)

Comment: This does not deserve the downvotes, since most pages do not say `change variable name in program`. He just didn't know the term

Comment: Which IDE are you using? The answers will depend heavily on that. It is not be possible with every IDE. You could possibly also use a command-line tool, especially if the variable name's text appears nowhere other than when used as the variable name - that would make this question very broad (too broad).

Comment: @Midnightas This question does not show any research effort and is underspecified - downvotes seem justified.

Comment: @Dukeling I am using BlueJ

Comment: @Midnightas What is the technical term then?

Comment: @LinuxGeek refactoring

Comment: I don't believe you can do this in BlueJ, but then I haven't used it in like a decade (someone else might be sure enough to post an answer). This can be done in both NetBeans and Eclipse, which are often recommended if you're looking for a feature-rich IDE.

Comment: @Dukeling I just installed Eclipse. It feels like a huge drift compared to the basic BlueJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open your project in eclipse and use inbuilt "refactor" mechanism of eclipse IDE.

Comment: Any chance of this also being in BlueJ?

Comment: I have not worked in BlueJ but as per the articles I read from google, yes it is possible in BlueJ also.